# Meaning of Related Tags number

Tags: support, tags

Just a question by curiosity:

When I click on ***Questions*** I see ***Related Tags*** on the right side of the page.

Let's say I see `Python x 564980`: does this number include questions and their answers, or just the questions themselves?

Comment: It's just the number of questions.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. IF you're sure about that then I would accept your eventual answer.

Comment: Trying to find a more canonical reference or something.  My comment would currently be a pitiful (yet correct) answer.

Comment: No, it's the number of closed questions with more than three downvotes.

Comment: I read your interesting answer (which seems to be right for me) but what do you think about Will's comment @ryanyuyu

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ Will is totally joking.  If you hang around meta more often you learn to take his stuff with a grain of salt because he cracks a lot of jokes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number next the tag represents the number of questions in that tag.  If you hover over the tag, the hovertext explains that this is the number of questions in that tag.

> [image: hovertext]

However, in general related tags are meant to filter from a broad tag to include more specifically tagged questions.  For example, if you visit the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag, you see [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) as a related tag.  The number there is *not* the number of questions tagged [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7), it is the number of questions **tagged with both [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [pythong-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pythong-2.7)**.  On the new navigation, the hovertext makes this clear.

> [image: New nav tags related to python]